# How should I structure two types of Roles in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application that has two kinds of "Roles".

- One will be where a user has multiple roles, such as "Admin", "Team Lead", etc. these will be defined in the seeds file and not generated by the user.
- The other will be generated by a User and assigned to other users, such as "Chef", "Waiter", etc.

They are both similar in that they only have a `name` column. The former will be used with an authorization tool such as CanCanCan. I currently plan to allow users and roles to have many of the other using a `has_many :through` relationship.

```
class Role
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

My questions are:

- Should the latter ("Chef", "Waiter", etc) be put in the same table? Separate tables?
- Should I use some kind of inheritance?
- What's a good practice for this situation?

I plan to use the term "Role" in the user interface for the latter, showing what "Roles" a user has. The former I guess is more about what privileges they have within the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go away from the technical side of roles and authentication, and try to describe the "things" from a more business oriented approach you make the distinction clearer for yourself.

What I understand is: You have a definition for a user of your application that is used to describe what authorization this user has, e.g. an "admin" has more rights than an "editor" or "community manager".

You also want these users of your application to be able to create names that are associated with (other?) users. Theses names have nothing to do with authorization, as I understood.
Maybe these names are more like tags, that people can assign?
I would keep both separated, as it shouldn't be able for a user to create a role, or modify existing roles, that could grant them access to admin features.

If you want to look at a tagging gem, I could recommend this one: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on I used this for several years and while it has its drawbacks, it's reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) before rolling your own solution, as it will have solved some things that you'll have to reimplement / discover later (e.g. role queries, avoiding N+1 queries etc). It also integrates well with `can?`, and should work well for the authorisation part of your question.

Whilst it's not impossible to allow users to create new roles (by throwing an input form on top of `Role.create`), this starts to get messy, as you need to track which ones are for authorisation and which ones informative (and user created).

Since the two groups of things are for different purposes, I wholeheartedly agree with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049697/7671538) that it's cleaner to separate the user-generated entities, and look to implement them as tags. You may display all the "roles" together in certain views, but that doesn't mean that it makes sense to store them within a single table.

---

**Side-note:** if you do end up rolling your own solution, consider using [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) here. The join table will still be created, but you won't have to manage the join table model. E.g.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :users_roles
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have a limited number of roles, you could use a bitmask and store directly on the user model as a simple integer.

See this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) for more information. That would be the most efficient, database and association wise, way to do this although perhaps not the simplest to understand. The only real restriction is that you can't alter the array of values you check against, only append to it.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately it's slightly more complex than that. There are indeed only a limited number of roles for the permissions. But the "Chef", "Waiter", etc will actually be created dynamically. So maybe I could take the bitmask approach for the permission side of things, and then use `has_many :through` for the other... interesting. I'll do some thinking on this.

Comment: nah in that case go with fully fledged associations. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would create one more model, Permission, where you can create a list of all the permissions you want to manage under any given role.

Then have a many to many between Permissions and Roles.

From a UserRole instance then you will be able to list the permissions, and in the future you could add additional permissions to roles buy just running inserts in a couple of tables

Roles: Onwer, Chef, Cook, Waiter
Permission: can_cook, can_buy_wine, can_manage, can_charge_custome

Owner: can_manage, can_buy_wine, can_charge_customer
Chef: can_cook, can_manage
Waiter: can_charge_customer

Is would be a good start and you can evolve the role functionality to whatever your needs are without an external dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Also, You can go just using `Users` table and adding `role` column as integer and give them a role code in default 0 integer.

```
#app/helpers/roles_helper.rb

module RolesHelper
  @roles = {
    'Default' => 0,
    'Waiter' => 10,
    'Chef' => 20,
    'Superadmin' => 30
  }

class << self

  def list_roles
    @roles.map{|k,v| [k,v] }
  end

  def code(str)
    return @roles[str]
  end

  def value(id)
    return @roles.key(id)
  end
end

  def require_default_users
    unless current_user && current_user.role >= RolesHelper.code('Waiter')
      redirect_to root_url(host: request.domain)
    end
  end

  def require_superadmin_users
    unless current_user && current_user.role >= RolesHelper.code('Superadmin')
      redirect_to courses_path
    end
  end
end
```

#### access in controllers

sample:

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
 include RolesHelper


  def sample_action_method
    require_default_users #if non admin user redirect ...

    puts "All Roles: #{RolesHelper.list_roles}"
    puts "Value: #{RolesHelper.value(30)}"
    puts "Code: #{RolesHelper.code('Superuser')}"
  end
end
```